# Does my sentence require a question mark?

Tags: grammar

Consider the brief passage below:

> There are two questions to be asked. Firstly, whether John was willing
>   and able to do his job. Secondly, what tasks did John have to complete
>   to satisfy his duty.

Does the last sentence (beginning with 'Secondly') require a question mark or does it correctly end with a period?

Comment: As it is currently phrased, it requires a question mark.  Rephrasing it as *Secondly, what tasks John had to complete to satisfy his duty* changes that.

Comment: No, it does not require a question mark. The entire sentence after "Secondly," is just a noun phrase. And why did you **not** have the same question in the case of the first sentence? How's that different or an exception?

Comment: @Kris it's not true that the second sentence consists of only *secondly* and a noun phrase. a free relative clause does not have auxiliary inversion, which is seen in the op's example. e.g., you can say *what you have done with my book is steal it*, but not **what have you done with my book is steal it.*

Comment: @jlovegren That example is not similar to the OP's.

Comment: @Kris if you please: *You must write down two things: first, the capital of Syria. Second, what you ate for breakfast.* putting in *...did you eat...* in the second sentence is non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide questions in English in to three basic groups:

1. Polar (yes/no) questions
2. Content questions where the questioned element is the subject
3. Content questions where the questioned element is not the subject

Examples of direct questions of types 1--3.

1. Did Thomas buy a dog?
2. Who bought a dog?
3. What did Thomas buy?

Examples of direct questions of types 1--3.

1. I don't know whether Thomas bought a dog.
2. I don't know who bought a dog.
3. I don 't know what Thomas bought.

*Direct* questions of types 1 and 3 require [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) (if no other auxiliary is present). *Indirect* questions of type 1 use the special interrogative word *whether*. In written English you usually put a question mark at the end of a sentence containing a direct question. As one commenter suggests, reword the second sentence so that it has an indirect question and not a direct question.